# How to test asynchronous behavior of this view model in NUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, nunit, async-await

My view model has a public method `void StartBroadcastingAndDiscovery()`.
This triggers two private async methods `Task StartBroadcasting()` and `Task StartDiscovering()`.
Both of these private methods are (endless) while loops like this:

```
while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
{
  var discovered = await this.networkService.Discover();
  this.DiscoveredPeers.Add(discovered);
  await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

The idea is that the async method used for discovery is polling the network service regularly. The network service is injected:

```
this.networkService = ServiceContainer.Resolve<INetworkService> ();
```

The user of the model can get a list of discovered peers. The list can change over time as peers appear or disappear from the network. At some point, the user calls `void StopBroadcastingAndDiscovering().`

In order to test my view model I have created a mockup network service that will "discover" three different peers. First request returns first peer, then the second, then the third and then the first again and so on.

My problem is now: how do I actually run the test? What can I test here? I would like to see that the list of discovered peers contains three items after 3 seconds but I don't want to hardcode the 3 secs delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to refactor `Task.Delay` to a separate, protected method inside your class like this:

```
protected Task Wait()
{
    return Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Then inside your unit tests, you inherit from your system under test and override the Wait method:

```
protected override Task Wait()
{
   return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

This way, your unit tests will call the overridden version of Wait that returns immediately. This skips the one second wait and makes your unit tests a lot faster and easier to control.

Extracting to a protected method is called creating a seam. You can also create seams by using interfaces and dependency injection but that looks like overkill to me for this situation.

Comment: Would adding a "delay" property be a valid approach too?  I would then set it to 0 for the test.

Comment: Yes. But then you would have to make clear that the property should only be set from a unit test. Overriding is a somewhat bigger step to take but both could work. The idea is: create a seam and remove the delay when you are working in your unit test.

Comment: I like the idea of overriding a protected method instead of the usual approach of interfaces with DI (which IMO often overcomplicates designs for the sake of unit tests). An alternative approach is to use [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) (VS Ultimate only).

Comment: @StephenCleary If you have some time left you should read the book Working Effectively with Legacy Code (http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052). it describes a lot of ways to make code more testable without going overboard with DI